# how to fetch all model instances in "many to one - belongs to" relationship which belongs to the parent model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

May be a naive question but here it is:

Suppose I have a device model, admin model, and a user model. Admin creates the devices. So admin has_many devices. Now each device belongs_to a user. 
This relation is defined as:

- admin ***has_many*** devices (devices are created by admin and he
  chooses a user at the time of creating)
- device ***belongs_to*** user

in the above relationship, I need to retrieve all the devices of a particular user. How do I do that in loopback?